# Why does the Youtube API work on my developer machine, but not on the live server?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-api

I'm trying to do a simple request to the Youtube API to get the videos associated with my client's channel. I've gone through the steps to activate the API and gotten an application key. I whitelisted my own development IP and the real server IP. The API call works fine from my development machine, but the live server gets a 403 error, 'Access Not Configured.' Has anyone seen this and solved it?

Comment: Can you post some code so someone can better assist you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first intention would be to go to the developers console

https://console.developers.google.com/project

Choose Project > APIs & auth > APIs > Credentials

and check the allowed IPs of the server key.

Moreover it could have something to do with how you get the content. Do you use curl?

Comment: Solved: the whitelisted IP did end up being the issue, due to one of the gotchas of shared hosting. The IP of the server making the API call was not the same as the IP associated with the URL. I'll mark your answer as accepted.